# Mac OSX alternative for TextWrangler

Tags: macos

I'm new to all of this, starting from scratch, and looking for the current best alternative for Mac OS X 10.11 for [TextWrangler now that it's discontinued](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) on how to ask for software recommendations. Also, there are a whole bunch of Q&As about editors already on this site where the answers should give you a lot of options to try.

Answer (score 9):

TextWrangler was always a feature-subset of the paid, full-featured [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/), from barebones.
Without a paid license, BBEdit runs just like TextWrangler & is a direct replacement for it.

Same maker, same look, same feature-set, opens all your saved documents, runs without an added license. The only action you need to do is install the app.

Ref: [BBEdit FAQs for TextWrangler Customers](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/faqs.html)

Comment: TextWrangler was always a subset of BBEdit, so you shouldn't have to relearn any shortcuts or how things work with the unregistered version of BBEdit.

Answer (score 3):

I switched to Atom. A free editor with a ton of options. It is very good if you plan on programming. For just writing memos and things like that I now use TextEdit which comes with OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Several of my developers swear by [Brackets](http://brackets.io/).

There's also the venerable [TextSoap.](https://www.unmarked.com/textsoap/)